# Writing simulation for job Queue

Tags: java, linked-list, queue, simulation

First off: this is NOT a homework assignment, it's my friend's that she has already completed and submitted and i got curious as to how it would work since I've never written a queue simulation before and decided to give it a shot.

basically, we are given a Job ADT and are supposed to write a functioning Queue ADT with regular queue operations like delete() and insert(). Using these two ADTS i am trying to write a job queue simulation in which there is an input file given which lists on line 1: the number of jobs to be processed, and all other lines in the file have pairs of numbers which represent arrival time and duration of each job on each line. There are more jobs than processors, and a job is made up of (arrival time, duration, finish time).

the goal of the simulation is to determine

1. total wait time
2. maximum wait time
3. average wait time.

I've written a functional Queue ADT based on `LinkedList` but am very lost as to how I am supposed to use both the `Job` ADT and the `Queue` ADT in the `Simulation` file. I know that my Queue ADT works, so i'm just including the Interface file for that to save space. I also have some code and some pseudo code for the Simulation file I've been working on. If i could just get a little bit of a push/ some example code i could probably find my way from there. Please help! :) thank you

example input file:

```
3,
2 2,
3 4,
5 6,
```

`input.rpt` file (report file created by simulation.java):
Report file:

```
3 Jobs:
(2, 2, *) (3, 4, *) (5, 6, *) 

***********************************************************
1 processor: totalWait=4, maxWait=3, averageWait=1.33
2 processors: totalWait=0, maxWait=0, averageWait=0.00
```

`input.trc` file (trace file created by simulation.java):
Trace file:

```
3 Jobs:
(2, 2, *) (3, 4, *) (5, 6, *) 

*****************************
1 processor:
*****************************
time=0
0: (2, 2, *) (3, 4, *) (5, 6, *) 
1: 

time=2
0: (3, 4, *) (5, 6, *) 
1: (2, 2, 4) 

time=3
0: (5, 6, *) 
1: (2, 2, 4) (3, 4, *) 

time=4
0: (5, 6, *) (2, 2, 4) 
1: (3, 4, 8) 

time=5
0: (2, 2, 4) 
1: (3, 4, 8) (5, 6, *) 

time=8
0: (2, 2, 4) (3, 4, 8) 
1: (5, 6, 14) 

time=14
0: (2, 2, 4) (3, 4, 8) (5, 6, 14) 
1: 

*****************************
2 processors:
*****************************
time=0
0: (2, 2, *) (3, 4, *) (5, 6, *) 
1: 
2: 

time=2
0: (3, 4, *) (5, 6, *) 
1: (2, 2, 4) 
2: 

time=3
0: (5, 6, *) 
1: (2, 2, 4) 
2: (3, 4, 7) 

time=4
0: (5, 6, *) (2, 2, 4) 
1: 
2: (3, 4, 7) 

time=5
0: (2, 2, 4) 
1: (5, 6, 11) 
2: (3, 4, 7) 

time=7
0: (2, 2, 4) (3, 4, 7) 
1: (5, 6, 11) 
2: 

time=11
0: (2, 2, 4) (3, 4, 7) (5, 6, 11) 
1: 
2:
```

Job ADT:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Job{
  public static final int UNDEF = -1;
  private int arrival;
  private int duration;
  private int finish;

  // default constructor
  public Job(int arrival, int duration){
    this.arrival = arrival;
    this.duration = duration;
    this.finish = UNDEF;
  }

  // access functions
  public int getArrival(){return arrival;}
  public int getDuration(){return duration;}
  public int getFinish(){return finish;}
  public int getWaitTime(){
    if( finish==UNDEF ){
       System.err.println("Job: getWaitTime(): undefined finish time");
       System.exit(1);
    }
    return finish-duration-arrival;
   }

   // manipulation procedures
  public void computeFinishTime(int timeNow){finish = timeNow + duration;}
  public void resetFinishTime(){finish = UNDEF;}

  // toString
  // overrides Object's toString() method
  public String toString(){
    return "("+arrival+", "
              +duration+", "
              +(finish==UNDEF?"*":String.valueOf(finish))+")";
  }
}
```

Queue Interface: lists operations that the Queue ADT performs

```
public interface QueueInterface{

  // isEmpty()
  // pre: none
  // post: returns true if this Queue is empty, false otherwise
  public boolean isEmpty();

  // length()
  // pre: none
  // post: returns the length of this Queue.
  public int length();

  // enqueue()
  // adds newItem to back of this Queue
  // pre: none
  // post: !isEmpty()
  public void enqueue(Object newItem);

  // dequeue()
  // deletes and returns item from front of this Queue
  // pre: !isEmpty()
  // post: this Queue will have one fewer element
  public Object dequeue() throws QueueEmptyException;

  // peek()
  // pre: !isEmpty()
  // post: returns item at front of Queue
  public Object peek() throws QueueEmptyException;

  // dequeueAll()
  // sets this Queue to the empty state
  // pre: !isEmpty()
  // post: isEmpty()
  public void dequeueAll() throws QueueEmptyException;

  // toString()
  // overrides Object's toString() method
  public String toString();
}
```

What i have in Simulation.java so far

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Job;

public class Simulation{
  public static Job getJob(Scanner in) {
    String[] s = in.nextLine().split(" ");
    int a = Integer.parseInt(s[0]);
    int d = Integer.parseInt(s[1]);
    return new Job(a, d);
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    Scanner in = null;
    PrintWriter in.rpt = null;
    PrintWriter in.trc = null;
    in = new Scanner(new File(args[0]);
    in.rpt = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter);
    in.trc = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter);

    in.useDelimiter("\n");
    int m = in.next();
    for(int i = 1; i<m; i++){
      System.out.println(getJob(Scanner in));
    } 
    int n = 1;
    while(n<m){
    Queue[] Processors = new Queue[n];
    Processor[0] = new Queue();
    Queue[] Backup = new Queue[n];

  // Pseudo code for Simulation
  //    1.  check command line arguments 
  //
  //    2.  open files for reading and writing
  //
  //    3.  read in m jobs from input file
  //
  //    4.  run simulation with n processors for n=1 to n=m-1  {
  //
  //    5.      declare and initialize an array of n processor Queues and any 
  //            necessary storage Queues
  //
  //    6.      while unprocessed jobs remain  { 
  //
  //    7.          determine the time of the next arrival or finish event and 
  //                update time
  //
  //    8.          complete all processes finishing now
  //
  //    9.          if there are any jobs arriving now, assign them to a processor 
  //                Queue of minimum length and with lowest index in the queue array.
  //
  //    10.     } end loop
  //
  //    11.     compute the total wait, maximum wait, and average wait for 
  //            all Jobs, then reset finish times
  //
  //    12. } end loop
  //
  //    13. close input and output files
```

Comment: [Here's a tutorial](http://www.informs-sim.org/wsc06papers/001.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

As a fellow learner of Java (first programming language for me), I've run into similar mental roadblocks designing programs for both assignments and hobby. As such, I feel my recent experience overcoming similar class-interaction confusion may help the OP, and *any answers the community can provide that focus on design process rather than code snippets would help the OP, other learners, and I*.

Breaking down the requirements:

- total wait time doesn't require storing data about each individual Job as it's processed. Maintaining an int instance variable in Simulation that is incremented by each Job that waits, by the amount it waits, ends containing the total wait.
- Average wait time just divides total by m, no instance variable needed.
- Maximum wait time is the type of question where I have found myself asking for inspiration, so I'll elaborate on my process and hopefully it'll be the "push" you need.

The example report files give a clue about the structures necessary, and what state changes trigger reporting. The "Time:x" lines indicate that you'll need to artificially keep time, and everything inside that snippet will loop, including reporting. The loop in step 6 of your pseudocode is the earliest that seems reasonable.

Lines only print to the report when a Job is started or finished rather than printing potentially identical reports every time the "clock" increments. A Job starts when it is dequeued, so does an empty Queue really mean there are no Jobs in process? The answer to that question determines where certain snippets go in the logic structure.

Job.getWaitTime() will only return a value after the job has been started. Finish time is computed by Job.computeFinishTime() by passing the time the Job reaches the processor and does not require time to pass to set finish. Call this method only at the right time.

One of my rookie mistakes was storing all the wait times in an array, rather than storing only the max seen so far. AFAIK there is no need to store more, and Simulation should have an instance variable to store it.

If you make progress, I would find it instructive to see the code at your next breakpoint.

P.S. My (learner's) understanding of ADTs is that the Queue ADT would be better in generics, or written specific to Jobs rather than Objects.